# Using multer to save a base64 decoded image to a user collection and disk

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this two codes. first one uses multer to save a user with an image. For each user, it saves the uploaded image with a particular name in the avatar field and the same name for the image. if no image is uploaded then save noimage.png as a name in the avatar field.

The second one decodes a base64 string to a picture and saves it to the specific path but every time an image is uploaded is being overwritten.

Is it possible to implement both codes to have the functionality of the first one but decoding the image from a base64 string?

The base64 string is the result of a cropped image. I want the user to be able to crop an area of the image to display it as the avatar.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Register Proccess
router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res){


  const username  = req.body.username;
  const email     = req.body.email;
  const password  = req.body.password;
  const password2 = req.body.password2;
  const date      = new Date();


  if(req.file){
    var avatar    = req.file.filename;
  } else {
    var avatar    = 'noimage.png';
  }

  req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  let {errors, validationResults} = require('express-validator');

  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });

  } else{

    let newUser = new User({
      username:username,
      email:email,
      password:password,
      date: date,
      avatar: avatar
    });
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success','You are now registered and can log in');
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        });

      });
    });
  })
});
```

Second code

```
var upload = multer(); 

router.post('/crop', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
    let img = req.body.cropped;
    let image = img.split(';base64,').pop();

    fs.writeFile("public/images/uploads/out.png", image, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
    console.log('File created');
     if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } else {
        res.redirect('/crop');
      }
}); 
  });
```

Comment: I guess the best approach here is to overwrite the result of the first code using the second one. Still don't know how to do it synchronously. Anyone has an idea?